# How to make a DevExpress grid row blink?

Tags: wpf, devexpress

Trying to perform a simple red blinking effect for a single row in a DevExpress grid.

I've applied the following style on the grid's row:

```
<Style x:Key="AlertedRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRowContent}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Row.IsAlerted}" Value="False">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                    To="Red"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.500"
                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                            </ColorAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </ColorAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                    To="White"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.500" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

It causes the following exception:

***'System.Windows.Media.Animation.ColorAnimation' animation object cannot be used to animate property 'Background' because it is of incompatible type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.***

Also tried to change the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to `Background.Color` and got:

***Cannot resolve all property references in the property path 'Background.Color'. Verify that applicable objects support the properties.***

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"` is right. Try

```
<Style x:Key="AlertedRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type dxg:GridRowContent}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        ...
```

I guess Background is Null and so the Storyboard can not find something to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
```

worked for me.

Comment: Won't work for me - I guess that the issue is the null value.

Comment: Very similar one, with `Background.(0)` in the exception message.

Answer (score 0):

you can open a new thread. In this thread you use a loop. In this loop you can change the Backcolor of the row. In the loop you sleep the thread for 0.3 sec or something. So it should look like blinking.

regards